# Set Status Code for Deny from

Tags: .htaccess

I want to block out user agents and tell them that the file doesn't even exist (Status Code: 404)

My current htaccess (Status Code: 403):

```
RewriteEngine on 
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent UpdaterV* updater
Order Deny,Allow 
Deny from All
Allow from env=updater
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod-rewrite to get 404 status code :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 #--if user agent is not UpdaterV--#
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !UpdaterV [NC]
 #--404 the request--#
 RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```